# How to get fields values of a model in xml through Python in qweb report odoo 12?

Tags: python, xml, odoo, odoo-12, qweb

I want to get the values of a model in xml qweb report.But in xml model is considering as string so no iteration over it.
My code:

```
def print_report_status(self):
        active_ids=self.env.context.get('active_ids',[])
        prd_categ= self.env['product.category'].search([])
        datas={
               'ids':active_ids,
               'model':'report.model',
               'form' : self.read()[0],
               'categ':prd_categ,
               
               } 
        
        return self.env.ref('product_report.action_report_pr').report_action(self ,data=datas)
```

and in xml:

```
  <t t-foreach="categ"  t-as="c">
        <tr style="border:1px solid black;  text-align:left;">
                 <td width="20%" style="text-align:left;"><span t-field="c.name"/></td>
         </tr>
                    
   </t>
```

it is considering "c" as string not model.
Any suggestion please

Comment: instead of t-field, could you try using t-esc

Comment: make `categ` a list and append the categories in there as a dictionary of the desired values, then loop through that list in your xml

Comment: @Eric I tried  but main thing is "Model" is becoming string in xml so cannot get its values

Answer (score 0):

user10810227

You have to access the `data['categ']` instead of only `categ` in the `XML` `for-loop`.

Comment: I have tried this data['categ'].it says 
Error to render compiling AST
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable

Comment: try to print on report <t t-set="categ" t-value="data['categ']"/>. what will you get into this?

Comment: it gives the same error Error to render compiling AST TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable –

Answer (score 0):

my answer particularly will not be as to why the model is returned as a string but rather how you can get this report working.

1. You can query the model straight from XML and loop it in there like this

```xml
<t t-foreach="request.env['product.category'].search([])"  t-as="c">
   <tr style="border:1px solid black;  text-align:left;">
       <td width="20%" style="text-align:left;"><span t-field="c.name"/>/td>
   </tr>
</t>
```

2. In my second approach, as I earlier commented, you can pass a list of dictionaries using python and loop them in the XML.
   Something like

```py
def print_report_status(self):
    active_ids=self.env.context.get('active_ids',[])
    prd_categ= self.env['product.category'].search([])
    datas={
          'ids':active_ids,
          'model':'report.model',
          'form' : self.read()[0],
          'categ': [{'name': i['name']} for i in prd_categ]
    } 
        
    return self.env.ref('product_report.action_report_pr').report_action(self ,data=datas)
```

And then loop through the data as before in the XML.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can try this in your xml template

```
<t t-set="categs" t-value="categ"/>
<t t-foreach="categs"  t-as="c">
    *something here*
</t>
```